# local namespace is not picking multiple values for XSLT mapping

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Below is my xsl file, based on the condition MaterialSalesText is picking only the first value.

```
<xsl:element name="DMI">
            <xsl:element name="D_808">F</xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="S_723">
                <xsl:element name="D_801_7">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../*[local-name()='SalesOrganisationID']='FAB' and ../*[local-name()='DistributionChannelCode']='SF'">                  
                            <xsl:value-of select="..//*[local-name()='MaterialSalesText']"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Product/Note"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
```

`SalesOrganisationID` & `DistributionChannelCode`  & `MaterialSalesText` are under local namespace
`SalesOrganisationID` & `DistributionChannelCode` are at header level 
`MaterialSalesText` is at `Item`/`Product` level

`Note` is in under its own namespaces, and under `Item`/`Product` level.

`Note` and `material` are repeating multiple times based on Item, based on the condition still it is writing only the first value.

Comment: Please show a sample XML input, and also a working xslt so that we can check your namespaces declarations (if any). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor and have set the `version` attribute on your stylesheet to `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" ...>`? If you are using an XSLT 1 processor or an XSLT 2 or 3 processor in backwards compatibility mode (which you would get with `version="1.0"` in your code) then any `xsl:value-of select="foo"` only outputs the string value of the first selected `foo` element.

Only with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor and the right `version` number in your code an `xsl:value-of select="foo"` is supposed to output the (a space separated) list of all `foo` values.